# Regex missing matches

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code to specify my regular expression in python

```
import re                            # Import the regular expressions package
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      # Import the matplotlib package
  
# Read the log file
with open('myfile.log', 'rt',encoding="latin-1") as file:
    log_text = file.read()

# Define regular expressions for pattern matching
pattern = r'Function eval (\d+) at point \d+ has f = ([-\d.]+) at x = \[ ([-\d.]+) ([-\d.]+) ([-\d.]+)\]'

# Extract data using regular expressions
matches = re.findall(pattern, log_text)

# Extract eval_numbers and f_values
eval_numbers = [int(match[0]) for match in matches]
f_values = [-float(match[1]) for match in matches]
```

My log file looks like the following

```
Function eval 1 at point 1 has f = -0.258940971315798 at x = [ 3.  14.4 -6.5]
Initialising (coordinate directions)
Function eval 2 at point 2 has f = -0.2259040076585 at x = [ 3.5 14.4 -6.5]
Function eval 3 at point 3 has f = -0.258912721121113 at x = [ 3.  15.9 -6.5]
Function eval 4 at point 4 has f = -0.259008279995406 at x = [ 3.  14.4 -5.8]
Function eval 5 at point 5 has f = -0.305466875532906 at x = [ 2.5 14.4 -6.5]
Function eval 6 at point 6 has f = -0.258922045649132 at x = [ 3.  12.9 -6.5]
Function eval 7 at point 7 has f = -0.258959151282265 at x = [ 3.  14.4 -7.2]
Beginning main loop
Function eval 8 at point 8 has f = -0.34817783367277 at x = [ 2.00000006 14.39986872 -6.49967721]
Function eval 9 at point 9 has f = -0.562108249792704 at x = [ 5.72367526e-08  1.43999223e+01 -6.49980500e+00]
New rho = 0.01 after 9 function evaluations
Function eval 10 at point 10 has f = -0.325941420427775 at x = [ 0.07158739 14.41254181 -6.5305591 ]
Function eval 11 at point 11 has f = -0.562106040838141 at x = [ 0.         14.35760572 -6.39667873]
Function eval 12 at point 12 has f = -0.308741672869589 at x = [ 6.97916734e-03  1.45423240e+01 -6.48009766e+00]
Function eval 13 at point 13 has f = -0.562119294825946 at x = [ 0.         14.25262353 -6.51302969]
Function eval 14 at point 14 has f = -0.322997122706926 at x = [ 0.04000959 14.17489323 -6.53416455]
Function eval 15 at point 15 has f = -0.562174526503614 at x = [ 0.         14.34595835 -6.56782799]
Function eval 16 at point 16 has f = -0.562187783721323 at x = [ 0.         14.32118157 -6.49878953]
Function eval 17 at point 17 has f = -0.562178945506711 at x = [ 0.         14.20668383 -6.45356794]
New rho = 0.001 after 17 function evaluations
Function eval 18 at point 18 has f = -0.562150223228322 at x = [ 0.         14.3725033  -6.52431188]
Function eval 19 at point 19 has f = -0.30923561054078 at x = [ 8.00416661e-03  1.43249728e+01 -6.49891060e+00]
Function eval 20 at point 20 has f = -0.562145804676754 at x = [ 0.         14.33349049 -6.48225911]
Function eval 21 at point 21 has f = -0.564667972452139 at x = [ 3.44362129e-03  1.43268836e+01 -6.49446789e+00]
Function eval 22 at point 22 has f = -0.564476463041547 at x = [ 3.17296828e-03  1.43150903e+01 -6.49015891e+00]
New rho = 0.0001 after 22 function evaluations
Function eval 23 at point 23 has f = -0.563516144031397 at x = [ 1.78656684e-03  1.43313574e+01 -6.49288379e+00]
Function eval 24 at point 24 has f = -0.564680143588853 at x = [ 3.47138233e-03  1.43297133e+01 -6.49561561e+00]
Function eval 25 at point 25 has f = -0.564590127687801 at x = [ 3.30886293e-03  1.43308568e+01 -6.49396456e+00]
Function eval 26 at point 26 has f = -0.564689063616869 at x = [ 3.51710529e-03  1.43310012e+01 -6.49596869e+00]
Function eval 27 at point 27 has f = -0.564386329819354 at x = [ 3.06544700e-03  1.43309346e+01 -6.49626736e+00]
Function eval 28 at point 28 has f = -0.564987691201283 at x = [ 3.97493644e-03  1.43315974e+01 -6.49592662e+00]
Function eval 29 at point 29 has f = -0.565043509875675 at x = [ 4.07612511e-03  1.43313188e+01 -6.49659970e+00]
Function eval 30 at point 30 has f = -0.565023413882358 at x = [ 4.02815339e-03  1.43322001e+01 -6.49716216e+00]
New rho = 1e-05 after 30 function evaluations
```

I want to extract the f value at each function evaluation, however I only seem to get random events returned, like 4, 8, 15 etc.

Are there any ideas on how to better define my regex expression to capture every function evaluation?

I have tried forcing the encoding and file handling as text or binary but it makes no difference.

The logfile is being created by the PyBobyQa optimisation logging output.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple consecutive spaces in the input within the square brackets, but the regexp matches only a single space. You may want to replace some spaces with  `+` or  `*`. Also, you should add `+` and `e` as valid characters in numbers.

```
pattern = r'Function eval (\d+) at point \d+ has f = ([-\d.]+) at x = \[ *([-+eE\d.]+) +([-+eE\d.]+) +([-+eE\d.]+) *\]'
```

In general, you may want to make whitespace matching more permissive, to avoid parsing errors in the future:

```
pattern = r'Function\s+eval\s+(\d+)\s+at\s+point\s+\d+\s+has\s+f\s*=\s*([-\d.]+)\s+at\s+x\s*=\s*\[\s*([-+eE\d.]+)\s+([-+eE\d.]+)\s+([-+eE\d.]+)\s*\]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with the part of your pattern that matches `x`. Firstly, you only allow for one space between values, where some of your lines have two or more. Secondly, you don't allow for exponents in the values (as in eval 9). Finally (at eval 10) there is a space before the closing `]`. Changing that part of the regex to this will fix that:

```
x = \[ ([-+\d.e]+) +([-+\d.e]+) +([-+\d.e]+) *\]
```

i.e.

```py
pattern = r'Function eval (\d+) at point \d+ has f = ([-\d.]+) at x = \[ ([-+\d.e]+) +([-+\d.e]+) +([-+\d.e]+) *\]'
```

For the first 10 evals of your text, `re.findall` will now return

```
[
 ('1', '-0.258940971315798', '3.', '14.4', '-6.5'),
 ('2', '-0.2259040076585', '3.5', '14.4', '-6.5'),
 ('3', '-0.258912721121113', '3.', '15.9', '-6.5'),
 ('4', '-0.259008279995406', '3.', '14.4', '-5.8'),
 ('5', '-0.305466875532906', '2.5', '14.4', '-6.5'),
 ('6', '-0.258922045649132', '3.', '12.9', '-6.5'),
 ('7', '-0.258959151282265', '3.', '14.4', '-7.2'),
 ('8', '-0.34817783367277', '2.00000006', '14.39986872', '-6.49967721'),
 ('9', '-0.562108249792704', '5.72367526e-08', '1.43999223e+01', '-6.49980500e+00'),
 ('10', '-0.325941420427775', '0.07158739', '14.41254181', '-6.5305591')
]
```